# Can we turn off firewall rules for IPv6 on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall, rules

By default (fresh installation) of Windows Server 2012 R2, I saw that there are several windows firewall rules which contains `ICMPv6-In` and `ICMPv6-Out`.

Is it ok for us to turn off these firewall rules if we don't use IPv6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really have IPv6 enabled and firewall on to be honest.

Here's a [short article](http://www.anexinet.com/blog/two-common-mistakes-windows-firewall-and-ipv6/) about it.
I'm also not sure what you mean by "Don't use it".

1. "Don't use it" - it will still be enabled just not used and you should have some security on it.
2. "Have unchecked the IPv6 box" - It is still not fully disabled and you should have some security on it. Also there are a lot of articles on why not to do this.
3. "Have cleared it from the registry" - Fair play, not recommended but I suppose if it's completely cleared then there's no danger of receiving traffic on it and so in my eyes you could disable those rules, but I also see no major downside to leaving them enabled -just-in-case-.

Hope this is of some help!

Comment: By "Don't use it', I mean I don't really have the need for IPv6 and not applying it to any of our application or `nginx`.
By the way, thanks for the article. I think it will be best leave it on